# Blocking VM's network temorarily from host machine in KVM

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to perform few changes to a running VM's MAC address and obtain new IP address.  Currently the VMs are connected to the outside network through the host's bridge interface. I would like to temporarily (10-20 seconds) block the VM's network connection from the host machine except for the packets relating to dhcp.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can either disconnect the VM from the host network, or just apply relevant `iptables` or `ebtables` rules to block packets from going anywhere.

Without more details of how your network is setup, it's impossible to give you more detailed commands, but they're all basic administrative tasks.

Comment: Ok great.... Now the VM communicates through the host's bridge interface. Please let me know what information you need. Moreover, I want to know whether it is possible to block the VM's network without blocking the dhcp packet which is required for acquiring a new IP ? Thanks for the info.

Comment: Add relevant information to your question, not comments.

Comment: Sorry , I will add that information with the question now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bridged networking for the VM, simply remove the VM's interface from the bridge adapter, perform the changes, then add it back.
If the host is linux os, you need the bridge-utils package installed (probably it is already).
Run this:

```
brctl show
```

to see what bridge devices are up and running, identify your bridge name and your VM network adapter, then remove it from bridge:

```
brctl delif brdev0 vmdev0
```

Do what you need to do on the VM and when you're done, add it back to the bridge:

```
brctl addif brdev0 vmdev0
```

PS: the above commands should be ran as root.

Comment: But this will not give vms the capability to send dhcp packet over the network right ! The best solution for me will be like filtering it out from iptables and let dhcp packets alone to pass through it for initial few minutes. But I am not sure about the rules.

Comment: Err, do you mean that you should re-phrase your question to: "Can you give pointers to basic IP tables HOWTOs/tutorials?

Comment: No , After getting your answers , I feel iptables will be my best solution and removing it from the bridge will not let me send the dhcp packet out. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your point is to find a way to apply filters per a specific VM instance from the host side? Applying the filters to the host's outgoing interface is not different from any normal *iptables* setup, but then the VM's will be able to communicate between each other unfiltered.

Have you tried applying normal *iptables* and *ebtables* rules to the corresponding *vnetNNN* interfaces in the host? I have not tried it myself but I think there is a good chance that it would work.

If you are using *libvirt* to manage your QEMU/KVM instances, you can do `virsh dumpxml VMNAME` and look for a line such as `<target dev='vnet0'/>` to see the relevant vnet interface.

Comment: Yeah the interface is vnet0.